# Is WER able to capture a full user-mode crash dump if not enough RAM is available?

Tags: windows, windows-error-reporting

Windows Error Reporting (WER) allows for automatic user-mode crash dump collection in the event an application crashes:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wer/collecting-user-mode-dumps

When a crash occurs, I have observed that WER creates a copy of the process in-memory, captures the dump, and then releases the memory and allows the crashing application to finish crashing.

Given the above, does WER still capture the full crash dump if there isn't enough memory available for a copy of a process to be made? For example, assuming a server has 16 GB Total RAM and an application process that normally uses 9-10 GB RAM crashes, would WER still be able to capture a full dump in this scenario given that it does not have enough memory available to create a copy of the crashing process like it usually does?

I've looked around for info on this from Microsoft but have not seen anything within their documentation (perhaps I wasn't looking hard enough or using the wrong terminology)

Comment: __Automatic Memory Dump - Windows drivers | Microsoft Docs__ 
If the computer crashes and the paging file is not large enough to capture a kernel memory dump, Windows increases the size of the paging file to at least the size of RAM. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/automatic-memory-dump   I used your __does WER still capture the full crash dump if there isn't enough memory available__ for a search.

Comment: @vssher does this apply to user-mode crash dumps as well? I did find this before but this is specifically for kernel-mode and the same isn't present in the user-mode section. my question is specific to user-mode dumps.